# spell check in batch mode on windows

Tags: windows, batch-processing, spell-checking

I have a folder with many text files that contain text extracted from latex files using omegaT.

I would like to run a spell check on all of these files at once, and get some type of report showing the list of misspelled words with their locations in files

I have seen some post related to aspell and linux.

Is it possible to do such batch spell checking on windows?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Have you tried writing a program to do this?

Comment: It is not exactly related to programming, I search for a solution,  tools any suggestions how to achieve this. If I considered writing a programm I would still need some lib to do the spell check

Comment: Then it's offtopic. Both code writing requests, and software recommendation requests are offtopic.